# How do I stop Microsoft Outlook from scrolling to the top of the message on every autosave?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, scrolling

Sometimes, I write a long e-mail in Microsoft Outlook.  Usually, it is a good idea to carefully review the content of such messages.

Unfortunately, every 2 minutes when Outlook automatically saves the message as a draft, the Compose window automatically jumps the scroll position to the top of the window, even when my hands are nowhere near the mouse or keyboard.  This is very poor design.  Every time that happens, I have to scroll back down, try to figure out where I was in the review, and re-establish context.  Shortly thereafter, the process repeats.

Is there any way to prevent that scroll-jumping behavior?
I would prefer an answer that does not require disabling the automatic draft saving.

Comment: This is a very old problem that was never really solved. Some workarounds were claimed which I don't trust. I think that the best idea is to make saves less frequent or to turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't reproduce this issue on Outlook 365 version 1908 and Outlook 2013. The cursor was at its place where it was before auto save happened. What's the version on your side? Maybe I can help test again.

Here are suggestions you can try:

1. Install available updates for Outlook and Office
2. Repair Office

Open Control Panel > Programs and Features. Right click your Office suit and then choose Change. Click Repair.

Comment: I'm seeing it right now in Outlook 365 v1910, though I don't see it all the time, for reliable reproduction steps.  Initially I thought it only applied to messages that had been saved to and opened from Drafts, but that is not the case at present.

Comment: I think it only happens with certain emails. I haven't noticed this behavior for a long time, until this afternoon it suddenly decides to do it again...